# What does | do?

Tags: javascript

Just saw the code below for generating a random number with a range. But I don't quite understand the part that uses |. What does that do? How does that affect an integer return vs a normal floating number?

```
function rand(min, max, integer) {
 var r = Math.random() * (max - min) + min; 
 return integer ? r|0 : r;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR

Comment: It's like `Math.floor(r)` but shorter.

Comment: this is a bitwise or

Comment: Ugh, cryptic abuse of integer coercion. I'd rather use Math.floor

Comment: JavaScript truncates any non-integer numbers in bitwise operations, so its computed as 0|0, which is 0

Comment: No, not exactly,@Ja͢ck. Even in this specific case, `r|0` is more like `r => r<0? Math.ceil(r): Math.floor(r)` And that snippet doesn't even cover dealing with `Infinity` or `NaN` or more widely, type conversion by the bit-operator wich has slightly different rules than the regular conversion to a Number.